# Nginx FastCGI cache + Wp-Rocket + Google Pagespeed redirects to the same page on example.com/*/

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx, fastcgi

Im trying to set up Multiple caching (server + website) with Nginx fastcgi Cache + wp-rocket for nginx (https://docs.wp-rocket.me/article/37-nginx-configuration-for-wp-rocket) + google page speed.

When i Setup FastCGI cache, once a page inside my website, e.g:
example.com/page is first cached, then the rest of the pages:
example.com/anyotherpage, is being shown as the first page cached (example.com/page)

Im using normal FastCGI Configurations.

Any ideas what causes this conflict?